# Xamarin Forms Button Background

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms. I've just practice with button and I saw a problem when I clicked the button.
See the red rectangle on the image link I recorded below:

[image: https://z-p3-cdn.fbsbx.com/v/t59.2708-21/34086570_1911682319122715_4772903306714415104_n.gif?_nc_cat=0&_nc_eui2=AeF0XJtIuzu6CuR7oPNsnOOAQuxVAvQ_g0fp0PfBUh_5ouFaFQb-wpkv8cuueWQ25IsjKYP9Vedd0XLE2M3J2_uC_zFeag-rca1q7CCVSyweYQ&oh=52d818ede27be9b626abc9aee7e53fa0&oe=5B22C886]

I try to use the custom renderer and effect but the button don't show the clicked effect.

code is here

```xml
<ContentPage 
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:extension="clr-namespace:LearnXamarin.MarkupExtensions"
         x:Class="LearnXamarin.Views.SignInPage"
         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource appBackgroundColor}"
         Padding="10"
<StackLayout Spacing="10"
             HorizontalOptions="Fill">
<Image Source="{extension:EmbededImage LearnXamarin.Images.logo.png}"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       Margin="0,20,0,0" />
<Entry Placeholder="Email"
       Keyboard="Email" />
<Entry Placeholder="Password"
       IsPassword="True" />
<Button Text="Sign In"
        TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Green"/>
<Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="New to xamarin? " />
            <Span Text="Create account!"
                  ForegroundColor="Blue" />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Please post a link to an image hosting site. https://imgur.com/

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: What effect / code are you trying to apply? Update your question.

Comment: Why do I need to post a link to imgur.com @Steve

Comment: The question has code .

Comment: I mean when I use effect or custom renderer it's not show the clicked animation.

Comment: [Why does Stackexchange uses Imgur to host images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277844/must-we-use-imgur-for-images)

Comment: Thanks you @Steve

Comment: @khunsokheang, Are you tried any other mobiles?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried Galaxy s8, s8 plus, A5, A7,either emulators too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button with background color, ripple effect renders in upper left corner only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710747/button-with-background-color-ripple-effect-renders-in-upper-left-corner-only)