# Button with background color, ripple effect renders in upper left corner only

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ripple-effect

Button with background color when clicked ripple effect renders abnormally with a shaded or faded rectangular selection area in upper left corner only instaed of the whole button area.

[image]

VS 2017,
Xamarin 4.10.10.2,
Xamarin.Andriod SDK 8.3.3.2

Comment: This looks like the Ripple animation on Android.

Comment: I have seen this too and it seems to be like the new xamarin forms buttons click on certain devices look like this mostly the Samsung high end ones

Answer (score 1):

An issue has been opened related to this problem [Android Buttons shows ripple effect only on the upper left area of the button on Samsung devices when changing/setting the buttons background color](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2096) and it seems affecting Samsung devices running Android 8.0.0 and below only, meanwhile it is being solved by Xamarin team you can:

1. Use [Material Button](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual) which is not affected by this issue.
2. Or try one of the workarounds mentioned by the community in the GitHub link I have provided.